# Correct way of using ActiveRecord::Base.connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Because I am changing stuff in my app so often I decided to use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` to query my DB, this is convenient because I don't need to add relations and also because the queries are faster and more easy to write.

But whats the correct way of using things like:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute
and other methods.
```

As an example: how I query my `users` table.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '#{username}'").rows
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close()
```

Using the above example does `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close()` know what connection to close? (in this case I want to close the select_all)

Or should I use? (having this query on any model will return anything is in the query if I convert all to an array or to json)

```
query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?"
Model.find_by_sql([query, username])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better you can use `Connection Pool`

```
spec1 = database_a
ActiveRecord::ConnectionPool.open(spec1) do |conn|
   conn.select_all("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '#{username}'").rows
   conn.close
end

spec2 = database_b
ActiveRecord::ConnectionPool.open(spec2) do |conn|
   conn.select_all("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '#{username}'").rows
   conn.close
end
```

Comment: Can you walk me throw what is exactly happening using what you suggested? Thank you.

Comment: It is a way to use multiple database to execute queries and we can close the connection by database wise after operations "The way we can reduce this coupling is by passing the connection specification to the method that actually opens the connection".

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L461-467 this is how Each pool releases the connection it has using the current_connection_id

Comment: At the moment I just have one DB, does you example apply to my case?

Comment: as you are worried about closing connection so it is the best way to close the specific open connection as current_connection from that specification but if you use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close()` it di not specify any particular connection